# Nonlinear equation in two unknowns with unique solution over the field of complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that a linear equation with two unknowns can not have a unique solution. On the other hand a nonlinear equation in two unknowns such as $$a^2+b^2=0$$ has a unique solution $a=0$ and $b=0$ over the real numbers.

But does there exist a nonlinear equation in two unknowns which has a unique solution in the field of complex numbers?

Restrict the space of functions to the elementary functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function.

Comment: Can you clarify the sort of functions you are allowing? For example the modulus function is a non linear function that takes complex values.

Comment: If you have a polynomial $P(z,w)$ in 2 complex variables, then for each value of $z$ there's a value of $w$ such that $P(z,w)=0$ (since the complex numbers are algebraically closed), so there are lots of solutions.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I am thinking about the so called elementary functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please don't restrict the functions to only polynomials.

Comment: I have edited the question to state the allowed range of functions.

Comment: May I ask why are you voting to close the question? Is the answer trivial? What is it then?

Answer (score -1):

It can be any complex number. For example a special case of imaginary number as sum of two squares:

$ a = x + i y,  b = u + i v ,$

$  a^2 + b^2 =  ( x^2 - y^2 + u^2 - v^2) + 2 i (x y + u v) $

if $ ( a,b) = ( (1,1), (-1,-1)),$  then $ a^2 + b^2 = 4 i. $

Comment: I am not asking about the equation $a^2+b^2=0$. I am asking whether there exists a nonlinear equation in two unknowns which has a unique solution over the field of complex numbers. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have edited the question to avoid confusion.